# How can I monitor and log an application?

Tags: windows-10, logging, debug

I am trying to run an application but it closes after a few seconds without giving any error message.

Is there an application that will collect a log of everything that the application did which I can then read so that I can find out what is causing my issue?

I tried looking at windows event log but I need more aggressive logging.

Comment: A universal application like you describe does not exist.  It is up to the application to log what happens and what fails to a log file

Comment: some applications will accept a logging level parameter, check if your application is providing this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: Completely uninstall the software and check to make sure no lingering traces of the application are in the Windows Registry, then reinstall the latest stable version of the software.

The long answer is: Yes, it's possible to find out the cause of the crash and potentially fix it, but it may require C/C++ programming and debugging if it is running in Windows on the desktop.

The long answer:

I discovered this by accident as a beginner programmer, but if you have the Visual Studio program installed, whenever an application crashes, there will be an option to "Debug Program".

If you click on that, you can view the assembly code and set up breakpoints in the editor, then step line-by-line to see where the error was. If you have access to the application's individual files and are handy in C/C++ debugging AND the application is not significantly large, i.e. less than 50-100 source files, it may be a worthwhile exercise to run the application in debug mode in Visual Studio and find out where in the code it is crashing. If it's a large program, like Photoshop, Office/Word/Excel, etc. those internal source files will likely not exist at the user-level, so reinstalling the application may be your best bet.

I suppose the only caveat to this solution is if the application in question was actually Visual Studio.

Sorry this is a programming-centric answer, but it is the closest solution to your question. If anyone can add to, clarify, or build on my answer please feel free.